# JSON post encoding in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, http-post, json

I want to make bulk insert in java with http post to Elasticsearch server.
I initiate org.json.JSONObject from the json string, up to now everything is normal. However when I execute the post method, Elasticsearch return me that error:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [replyContent.value]];nested: JsonParseException[Invalid UTF-8 middle byte
```

The string contains turkish characters such as: ü, ç, ş...

I tried this code:

```
JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(new String(jsonString.toString().getBytes("ISO8859_9"), "UTF8"));
```

With this initialization, post has been worked, nevertheless, this time all the turkish characters were converted to ? character.

What could be the solution code for this problem, and where should it be? In initiation code of json object or when I post the json data?

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe share your code?

Comment: The code is; `String sb= new SearchService().execute("item", dateFormat.format(date));
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(new String(sb.getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF8"));` Then when I post the json, I convert it back to string again with the method toString `strBuffer.append(bindings.getJSONObject(i).toString() + "\n");`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with elastic search but rather with json.

based on the json rfc [4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) - json string needs to be encoded as unicode, thus having

> characters such as: ü, ç, ş...

is invalid json

Comment: So, what is the correct code for this? I wrote down the code I used.

Comment: @hakki first make sure that your string does not contain invalid characters (from json perspective), then you should be ok